# How to connect to webcam in Codetyphon base on Linux OS (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lazarus, freepascal, codetyphon

What component must I use to connect application to the webcam or camera which is build with CodeTyphon base on Linux Operating System like Ubuntu?

Comment: i'm sorry for my poor english grammar

Comment: [pxl](https://github.com/zyhh/pxl) and [5dpo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sdpo-cl/) includes camera support (not sure is it included into the CodeTyphon). However the question about software recommendations is offtopic for this site.